# SQL: Are nested replace() methods slow?

Tags: sql

I was wondering about the performance of nested REPLACE() methods in an SQL query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM CUSTOMERS 
WHERE Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(username, '.MR', ''), ' MR', ''), '.', ''), ' ', '') LIKE '%" & nameOnForm & "%'
```

I'm basically trying to strip any titles (Mr, Mrs, Dr) from the username, but I have a list of about 40 possible titles that I would need to strip. And as far as I know, using the nested REPLACE() methods is the only way to achieve this.

My question is, how does this affect performance of my query? Does it get bulkier and slower the more I nest? If so, is the difference in speed negligible or significant?

I could always run a benchmark test to see this for myself, but I was wondering as well if there are any better ways of doing what I am trying to do?

Comment: The non sargable `LIKE` will probably be slower than those replaces... can't you make a reference table?

Comment: If performance problems popup, store another version of the username, with all the replaces applied, in another column and search against that, rather than the original one.

Comment: I won't post this as an answer because I'm not sure, but it would make no sense to me if this was any worse than O(n). I mean, each replace takes a string and replaces a part of it, the amount of times you do it shouldn't matter.

Comment: @davida. Thanks for the reply, the thing is these usernames come in through an automated system, not anything the user creates. The nameOnForm doesn't contain titles. And I don't have access to the automated system's code.

Answer (score 1):

In general `REPLACE` is faster than a `TRANSLATE`. But in case of nested `REPLACE`, definitely performance might take a hit. Its safer to rewrite them and compare. Also I would suggest **function based index**.

Answer (score 0):

It's not just nested replace functions that are slow.  This sort of construct will always be slow when there are lots of records in the table.

```
where function(field) = something
```

For your particular problem, if you want speed, you have to bite the bullet and do something like this:

```
where username like '%Mr.%'
or username like '%Mrs.%'
etc
```